# How to click Login button

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Help me to find button ID or XPath on https://instant-stresser.com/login. I want to make bot that automaticly log ins because my code didn't work.

```
enter_searchbar = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
enter_searchbar.send_keys("myusrname") 
enter_searchbar = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
enter_searchbar.send_keys("mypass") 
button = driver.find_element_by_name("Login") 
button.click()
```

Error I get:

> Exception has occurred: No Such Element Exception Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[name="Login"]"}   (Session info:
> chrome=86.0.4240.198)

Comment: Have you tried class: "btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3 mt-2"? Or select element by text?

Comment: yes i tried if you mean driver.find_element_by_class_name and driver.find_element_by_link_text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see no elements with `@name="Login"`. Try this instead

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
```

Or as an option you can call `submit` method from any element found inside HTML `form` node:

```
enter_searchbar.submit()
```

Comment: Thanks it realy worked. But i want to know where I can find xpath

Comment: @EmilijaLinkuvičiūtė you can [create XPath by yourself](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) based on unique node attributes

Answer (score 1):

when u r on the website press `ctrl + shift + i` to open developer tools, then press `ctrl + shift + c` to open the selector tool, then click on the element on the page `(the button)`, go back to developer tools and now something should be highlighted, then right-click, `copy, copy full XPath,` then u can use this piece of code for clicking on an element that is clickable.

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH GOES HERE").click()
```